# How to create a password login modal, click submit button and open another modal containing links using bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a password login modal, click submit button and open another modal containing links using Bootstrap 3 and I am stuck and could use some help. I've already created the login modal(just a password input and submit btn -this is `#modal6`) and the modal containing the links(this is `#modal7`) that will pop up when the password is correct(just a single password, no user login etc...). Since this seems relatively simple I am trying to do this just using javascript/jquery and without mysql or php.  Well I am stuck... I can't figure out how once the correct password is submitted to bring up the modal window containing the links. I have figure out how to do this with a login modal and you click submit and with the correct password it will bring up the links if it is a html page Example:

```
<form` name="employee"
    action="javascript:location.href =window.document.employee.page.value + '.html'"
```

I cannot figure out how to do this with the links as a modal as opposed to a html page.

Comment: How are you processing if a password is valid? If it's stored on the server, you're going to have to access it somehow and javascript is not the way

Comment: Hey Mark - No the password is not stored on a sever, I was using this - "<form` name="employee"action="javascript:location.href =window.document.employee.page.value + '.html'"> and the password is the name of the page(employee). The client wants the page with the links to be a modal dialog window and not a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar challenge. I had to use a modal to add/edit an item and the result of that action (success/error) had to be displayed in a modal as well. The tricky part is to close the current modal and to open a new one again. Especially if there is not much time between closing one modal and opening another.

What I have done is combined the two. And maybe that could be a solution for you too. Create a modal with a body containing two sections, one for entering the password (checking and displaying the result if password is not ok) and one containing the links. When a password is needed, only the password section is displayed. When the password is correct, hide the password section and unhide the link section. Using this approach only one modal is needed. Using this approach, you won't have to bring up a new modal, just use the one that is open already.

Comment: Thanks Barry for the response... I like this, you wouldn't happen to have a js fiddle example of this code I could look at? I really appreciate your suggested solution! Seems like a good solution just not sure how to pull this code off... I am a noob to boostrap3 and the modal windows.

Comment: @jsavage980 Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ozzf3q4n/)?

Comment: Thanks Barry! Really appreciate the help...only thing now is I am wondering how the second modal with the links would appear only if the correct password(ex password:employee) is typed in the password input. Really appreciate the code example!

Comment: @jsavage980 Check [this modification](http://jsfiddle.net/ozzf3q4n/1/). Password = 'letmein'.

Comment: @jsavage980 Check [new version](http://jsfiddle.net/ozzf3q4n/2/). Bug removed when clicking in input.

Comment: Thanks again Barry! works great! thanks for sharing your knowledge with me!